# Sort div array based on alphabets during appending Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, sorting

I am stuck in a place where I have to sort the list of names when moved those list on button click.

```
sort()
```

method works fine but clicking on the same button again creating duplicates!, which is not I need.

Is there any way I can fix this. used below code too(which took from stackoverflow) even this is not working.

```
function SortByName(a, b) {
    var aName = a.name.toLowerCase();
    var bName = b.name.toLowerCase();
    return ((aName < bName) ? -1 : ((aName > bName) ? 1 : 0));
}
var selectArr = selectedList.sort(SortByName);
```

**MY CODE**

```
 $(document).on('click', '#buttonAdd', function (e) {
    var divCount = $('#SelectedEmployeeList').find('div').length;
    if (divCount === 0) {
        selectedList = []; // Clearing the list, to add fresh employee list.           
    }
    $('#EmployeeList :selected').each(function (i, selected) {
        selectedList[$(selected).val()] = $(selected).text();            
    });

    // Returning DOM node from collection.
    var empListNode = $("#SelectedEmployeeList")[0];
    console.log(empListNode);
    while (empListNode.firstChild) {
        empListNode.removeChild(empListNode.firstChild);
    }

    for (var empID in selectedList) {
        $("#SelectedEmployeeList").append("<div class= EmpList id=" + empID + ">" + selectedList[empID] + " <span class='close'>&times;</Span> </div>");
    }
});
```

This is the place where all sort should happen `#SelectedEmployeeList`.

have shared the pics for references.

Sort is happening correctly on the left like here :

[image]

after clicking on "Add All >> " items are moved but not sorted :

[image]

any help will be appreciated.

UPDATE 1 :

[image]

Comment: The `for...in` loop doesn't do what you want it to do. Also, instead of `selectedList[$(selected).val()] = ...` since `selectedList` is an array, you should push values into it `selectedList.push(...)` or change it to an object.

Answer (score 2):

This is your problem:

```
for (var empID in selectedList) {
        $("#SelectedEmployeeList").append("<div class= EmpList id=" + empID + ">" + selectedList[empID] + " <span class='close'>&times;</Span> </div>");
}
```

`For...in` iterates over an object in no order. Save your employees in an array and iterate over it:

```
var selectedList = [];
$('#EmployeeList :selected').each(function (i, selected) {
        // push an object into the selectedList array
        selectedList.push({
            empID : $(selected).val(),
            text: $(selected).text(),
            div: selected
         });            
});

// iterate over the array in order
for (var i = 0; i < selectedList.length; i++) {
        // appends a NEW div
        $("#SelectedEmployeeList").append("<div class= EmpList id=" + selectedList[i].empID + ">" + selectedList[i].text + " <span class='close'>&times;</Span> </div>");
        // MOVES the div
        $("#SelectedEmployeeList").append(selectedList[i].div);
}
```

Comment: Now it is not adding not even one list on to right side.

Comment: Your code works same as "sort() " method which does add the list to the right, but when clicked on the button again will add duplicate data!

Comment: Ofcourse it will add **new** divs to the right. That's what your code did already. If you want to **move** the divs from the left list to the right list, you have to append the actual div, not new HTML code.

Comment: Hmmm not exactly, i.e. if I don't need sort, if i just want to add list to right, then even clicking the button will not create duplicate items.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/124412/discussion-between-user2415266-and-manjuboyz).